# Extracting geometry data of classes in classified image or masking class layers using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I made an unsupervised image and extracted to classes as a new layers. I want to get and use those layers (subset1, subset2, subset3) geometry data. I will use this geometry datas in ".clip(subset1_geometry)" function.

How can I obtain geometry data of those layers?

```
var bands=['B4','B3','B2'];

var training=clipdata3.sample({
  region:geom,
  numPixels:101,
  scale:10
});

var grupo= ee.Clusterer.wekaKMeans(3).train(training)

var classified= clipdata3.cluster(grupo)

var subset1 = classified.select("cluster").eq(0).selfMask(); 

var subset2 = classified.select("cluster").eq(1).selfMask(); 

var subset3 = classified.select("cluster").eq(2).selfMask();
```

OR

I want to masking my layers with my collection data but my collection has 16 different band. The program tells me only one band can be masking but I want all bands of the collection data on subset layer.

```
var subset1 = classified.select("cluster").eq(2).mask(clipdata3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can turn your subset* images to geometries with `ee.Image.reduceToVectors()`, you should try to avoid it. EE is a lot happier to work with images compared to complex geometries.

I'm not completely sure I understood what you are trying to do here, but I think you want to mask your original image, `clipdata3`, based on your clusters. If so, you just need to turn your alternative solution around:

```
var subset1 = clipdata3.mask(classified.select("cluster").eq(0))
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/851da2e55ff1a2bb826841858875a6ec